# get method name in Pre/Post-Authorize

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am writing my own PermissionEvaluator for Spring security and one of the things I am trying to do is figure out the name of the method it is protecting.

For example, without the method name in picture I have something like:

```
postAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject,'read')")
Event getEvent(int evendId) {
...
}
```

and

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
    if(targetDomainObject instanceof Event) {

        return hasPermission(authentication, targetDomainObject, permission);
    }
    return targetDomainObject == null;
}
```

But I also need the method name "getEvent" to be available to the hasPermission. I can do this by manually passing it in in the hasPermission call, like so:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(new com.example.AuthZObject(returnObject,'getEvent'),'read')")
Event getEvent(int eventId);
```

but is there is more automated way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ralph very much has the right idea here. The first step is to create a custom implementation of MethodSecurityExpressionOperations that can store the Method on it and use it to evaluate an expression. For example:

```
public class MyMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;
    private Method method;

    public MyMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a) {
        super(a);
    }

    // allow the method to be set    
    public void setMethod(Method m) {
        this.method = m;
    }

    // optionally expose the method to be accessed in expressions    
    public Method getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    // create a method that will perform the check with 
    // the method name transparently for you    
    public boolean hasMethodPermission(Object target, Object permission) {
        boolean result = false;

        // do your calculations using the method member variable 
        // i.e. method.getName() and the arguments passed in
        // of course you could delegate to another object if you want
        // i.e.
        // return hasPermission(new com.example.AuthZObject(target,method.getName()),permission));
        // or you could do the logic right here

        return result;
    }

    // implement the interface and provide setters

    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject;
    }

    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return filterObject;
    }

    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
    }

    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return returnObject;
    }

    public void setThis(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public Object getThis() {
        return target;
    }
}
```

Next extend DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler and use the custom expression root.

```
public class MySecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler{

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation){
        MyMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new MyMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl());
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setMethod(invocation.getMethod());
        return root;
    }
}
```

Once you configure MySecurityExpressionHandler, you should be able to use the following:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasMethodPermission(returnObject,'read')")
Event getEvent(int eventId);
```

Comment: a real pity that `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` has package-private. IMVHO, `package-private` should die in the burning pits of hell in general; it's not encapsulation when you can still use that code by spoofing package name :}

Comment: also, don't forget to e.g. put `@Component` on `MySecurityExpressionHandler` or otherwise add it to the bean pool :}

Comment: BTW, I've found something _golden_: `@Override public StandardEvaluationContext createEvaluationContextInternal(Authentication auth, MethodInvocation mi) { var context = super.createEvaluationContextInternal(auth, mi); context.setVariable("_context", context); /* hic sunt dracones */ return context; }`, and then just pass `#_context` anywhere in your SpEL'ed method call... and then you can magically e.g. `Object resultOfSomeAdditionalSpEL = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(someAdditionalSpEL.value()).getValue(context);` ! this allows e.g. stitching annotations with SpELs at runtime!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether or not this is possible, but you should have a look at the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. This class has this two methods:

```
public final EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication authentication, T invocation) {
    SecurityExpressionOperations root = createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, invocation);
    StandardEvaluationContext ctx = createEvaluationContextInternal(authentication, invocation);
    ctx.setBeanResolver(br);
    ctx.setRootObject(root);

    return ctx;
}

protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
    MethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new MethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
    root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
    root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
    root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
    root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());

    return root;
}
```

I feel that you need to extend the class `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` with the additional fields you need, and then you need to subclass `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and replace the `createSecurityExpressionRoot` method so that it returns you extends `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` with the populated fields.

Then you can add new methods to your extended `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` that are able to access this additional fields.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I am in the process of doing something (working on extending MethodSecurityExpressionOperations) but has [hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237117/creating-custom-postauthorize-method-in-spring-security) another wall on the matter